# How to validate financial transactions in REST API with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, validation

I need to implement a Spring Boot app, it is about financial transactions. I want to create a REST API like this:

```
@PostMapping("/sendmoney")
public void sendMoney(@RequestBody TransferBalanceRequest transferBalanceRequest) {
    transactionService.sendMoney(transferBalanceRequest);
}
```

TransferBalanceRequest class:

```
public class TransferBalanceRequest {
    private String name;
    private String tin;
    private String fromIban;
    private String toIban;
    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

I need to validate in this way: payer si payee should have a valid IBAN and NIF and all the other fields shouldn't be empty.

So how ca I do this validation? Should I use this type of annotations?

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a name")
```

Answer (score 3):

[JSR-380 - Bean Validation 2.0 Spec](https://beanvalidation.org/)

Implementations (such as [Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/)) for this specification will provide you annotations that you can use on your request's fields, as for example the [@NotEmpty](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotEmpty.html) and [@Pattern](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html), for the scenarios that you mentioned.

Comment: Need to add @Valid on RequestBody.